# How can I find out which shared libraries I need to run a Java class on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, shared-libraries

I want to know what shared libraries I need to have available when running a particular Java application. I know how to get the library list for the Java interpreter (ldd java) but the application then goes on to do things with GUIs and sockets from the standard Java API.

So basically I want to know if there's some way I can find out what shared libraries a standard Java class in rt.jar (such as java.io.Socket or javax.swing.JFrame) will load behind the scenes, short of exhaustive path testing.

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You could get the [source code](http://openjdk.java.net/), links are on the left (just above "Groups"). Obviously, it'll vary by JDK. Assuming you want more then `ldd java`.

Comment: As I said, I know about ldd java, but it only reveals what the "java" command itself loads -- not e.g. sockets or GUIs. However I'll try groping around in the source -- at least it will not depend on runtime path coverage. Not a prefect solution, but thanks, I'll try it and report back.

Answer (score 0):

If the source is not available, then you could load the class via a custom `ClassLoader` and override `loadClass()` to report what classes are being loaded:

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader{
    public CustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
        super(parent);
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(name);
        return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
    }

}
```

and then run the class you want with the  JVM flag `-Djava.system.class.loader=CustomClassLoader`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch   I think that you also have to also override `findLibrary()`, because that is called each time a library is loaded.

Comment: This will only list libraries as they are loaded, so presumably may not list all libraries unless testing has 100% code path coverage.

Comment: Come to think of it, strace would do this job without writing a new classloader. But as I said, this would only show me what was loaded depending on path coverage. Which is not what I'm trying to achieve.